# Sql clone data from a column

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I need to copy the data from one field to another in the same table, I have more than 11,000 records. Attached image [image]

Comment: For just that one `post_id`, or for all or some of them?

Comment: i need for all..

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
  wp_postmeta  rating 
INNER JOIN
  wp_postmeta  review
    ON  rating.post_id = review.post_id
SET
  rating.meta_value = review.meta_value
WHERE
      rating.meta_key = '_wc_rating_count'
  AND review.meta_key = '_wc_review_count'
```

demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=773d28af0ea7a6c3c482ae09b09520e7